# Can you load an apache module from the .htaccess file?

Tags: apache

Like,   can I modify the .htaccess file to load an apache module?   Specifically,  does "ExpiresActive On" load the mod_expires module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`LoadModule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) directive can only be used in server config. Not vhost config and not in an htaccess file.

> Specifically, does "ExpiresActive On" load the mod_expires module?

No, if you try to use a module that's not loaded, you'll get a 500 internal server error.

Comment: If you set expires headers, wrapped in <IfModule mod_expires.c>, but mod_expires isn't loaded,  will it still 500 error?   Will the expire headers do anything if it's not loaded?

Comment: @swl1020 No, if you wrap the statements inside an `<IfModule>` container, then those won't be processed if the module isn't loaded. So you won't get a 500 error.