# getting 500 internal server error while hosting php mvc based site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to host a site for a first time and having problem while hosting the **php MVC** based site, **500 internal server error** is shown.

While I tried before in **localhost** (using wampserver) the same error occured but I managed to solve it by uncommenting the '***LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so***' statement in **httpd.conf**

But in cpanel there is no option to configure **httpd.conf**. I googled the problem but couldn't reach to the solution. Also I found out the httpd.conf is the global configuration and we don't have permission to access the file. So is there any way to solve **500 error**  through **.htaccess** configuration?

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mysitename.com

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well, execute a php file with line `<?php phpinfo() ?>` and look for `rewrite`. If you don't find anything related to "mod-rewrite" then change host.

Comment: Check your Apache error.log to see what the error is

Comment: So, you want to enable mod_rewrite. Therefore the question is 'can I load Apache modules through htaccess?'. No, you cannot. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068097/can-you-load-an-apache-module-from-the-htaccess-file

Comment: You can ask your host to enable it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for immediate response. Like @Forien told me, I did search for the "mod-rewrite" and couldn't find it. Also the error.log is empty, nothing is being displayed. Yeah JAL that's exactly what I want to say

Answer (score 0):

You may create a .htaccess file in the root of the application directory and add these directives inside it.

This works as a per-site settings. Whatever you put in httpd.conf is global.

Comment: Additionally check / add the default file is set to index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php

Comment: If you are getting errors inspite of this, part of the problem is elsehwere. Can you please post the error logs (apache / php) logs for reference. 
Couple of questions - why are you using RewriteBase /sitename.com? Its required if you are running your app inside a sub directory.
This link should help [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess

Bottom line - we will need more information to provide an answer.